# Why is this vector-set linear-dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\{ (1,0),(0,1),(0,0)\} $$

Maybe I'm losing it, but I can't see here a vector which is a linear-combination of the other two.

Comment: In the immortal words of Sesame Street: 

"One of these things is not like the others, 
One of these things just doesn't belong, 
Can you tell which thing is not like the others
By the time I finish my song?"

Answer (score 3):

It is simple. According to definition, if $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_nv_n=0$  while $v_i=0$ then all constants $c_j\in F$ where $1\le j\le n$ and $j\neq i$ could be zero but $c_i$. This contradicts the independence of the vectors $V/F$. So whenever the vector $v=0$ is included in any set of vectors then that set is linearly dependent.

Comment: got it! by the way, what is $V/F$?

Comment: $V/F$ means a vector space over a field.

Comment: Honestly I did not recognize this notation but it's good to say it since this notation is also used for the quotient vector space.+1

Answer (score 2):

$$0\cdot(1,0)+0\cdot(0,1)+42\cdot(0,0)=(0,0)$$
is a linear dependence between these and
$$ (0,0)=0\cdot(1,0)+0\cdot(0,1)$$
shows how to combine two of them to obtain the third.

Comment: So, I can use the vector itself to show linear-combination?

Answer (score 1):

A linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ looks like $a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}$, where $a$ and $b$ are numbers.
In your case
$$0\cdot \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right) + 0\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$$